# Python doesn't recognize regex pattern - Number between 1 and 6 digits

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, ocr

I have a problem, I try to recognize a pattern among a list of words. I need to find a number of 1 to 6 digits with or without characters around.

my input is this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNOdL.png

With the OCR I obtained:

```
Kundennummer:
21924
```

The pattern r"(\D|\A)+**\d{5}**(\D|\Z)+" works but when I change it to r"(\D|\A)+**\d{1,6}**(\D|\Z)+" it doesn't.

I used re.match, re.findall and re.search and none of them works

the repr():

```
'Kundennummer:'
'21924'
```

Comment: Can you show us the `repr` of that string? I think you may have some invisible characters in there.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem: https://regex101.com/r/ECKXkd/1 vs https://regex101.com/r/f6QXHb/1

Comment: @Anentropic Yes ! exactly that is why I don't understand why it is not working

Comment: @AKX I added the repr but if the first regex is working I don't get why the second don't

Comment: do you have one input string or two?

Comment: @JuMrd If you have multiple separate strings, then you could just use `s.isdigit()` to find a string that is all digits.

Comment: @Anentropic I have several, in this case 2

Comment: @AKX it won't work if there are letters attached to the number

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only need the first match:

```
import re

ocr_result = """
Kundennummer:
21924
"""

for result in re.findall(r'\d+', ocr_result):
    if 1 <= len(result) <= 6:
        break
else:
    result = None

print(result)
```

Result:

```
21924
```

Comment: It is a great idea but if the number is attached to a word which is too close it won't work

Comment: Could you provide an example please? It works with e.g. `Kundennummer21924abc` result: `21924`

Comment: No my bad it works pefectly tahnk you very much !

Answer (score 0):

```
ocr_result1 = """
Kundennummer:
21924
"""

ocr_result2 = """
Kundennummer:3000
"""

for e in [ocr_result1, ocr_result2]:
    print(re.findall(r'\w*\d{1,6}\w*', e))


['21924']
['3000']
```